# SQL move part of table data and replace by key of row in new table

Tags: mysql, sql

Example with 2 tables:

```
Table A: `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`   
Table B: `id`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`
```

I'm making a `Table C` that contains the `X`, `Y`, `Z` columns of either `A` and `B`, and use a key to link the data i.e.:

```
A `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `id_C`   
B `id`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `id_C`  
C `id`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`
```

Creating these tables isn't the problem.
The problem I have is changing the current data of `A`, `B` into `A`, `B`, `C`.

How do I accomplish that?

The only way I can think of is to add the id of `A` as a column in `C` while moving the data, than connect the two tables and then removing the id column of `A` again. After this do the same with `Table B`.

---

**EDIT**

I'm using MySQL 4.1.22

Comment: or you can build a new table 'in between' that links them both, You can easily keep a variable around in a SQL script, please indicate what database platform you are using for syntax help.

Comment: @Randy see edit, I'm not familiar with variables in SQL scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution:

1. Create `Table C` with columns `id, X, Y, Z` (id is auto-increment).
2. Add data to it, like this:

```
INSERT INTO C (X, Y, Z)
SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM (
    SELECT X, Y, Z FROM A
    UNION
    SELECT X, Y, Z FROM B) As tempC
```

3. Now `ALTER` tables `A` and `B` with adding a new column `id_C`.
4. Update the `id_C` like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET id_C = (SELECT id FROM C WHERE C.X = A.X AND C.Y = A.Y AND C.Z = A.Z)
```

5. (After doing 4 for both `A` and `B`) Drop  `X, Y, Z` from `A` and `B`.

Comment: just as I thought, is there no way to insert to C and set the id (A,B) in 1 query (drop columns after that)? B.t.w. Thanx for editing the question

Comment: @Marcel Those are two different tables, That you can update both of them in one time ;).

Comment: Well i was wondering if something like this is possible  (for each row in A, insert into C, get last insert id of C, update row in A with id). Of course the same applies to B

Comment: @Marcel So you should have `X, Y, Z` in `A` always then use a TRIGGER ;).

Comment: Well i think making a few more steps to be sure that the data stays correct is fine by me. I don't want to dive into the unknown :)